# Need a replacement for MVC's @Scripts.Render method

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Migrating from an MVC-pre-Core project to a Core 2 version I'm shocked to find @Scripts & @Styles are removed. I had relied on being able to use `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/myApp")` as a short cut that imported a half dozen files on any page that needed them. Now I have to spell all those files on each page that needs them?

Any way to replicate the behavior. Have glanced at Gulp but seems more like exclusively a processor for deployments.

Comment: re the anon downvotes... show me the passage in the migration docs where the updated flow is documented as well as the AA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Scripts.Render` and `Styles.Render` methods don't actually do anything other than add a simple tag to the generated HTML. The meat of what you're talking about - having a bunch of script/styles rolled up in one call - is the bundling provided by MVC. In ASP.NET Core, the method of creating those bundles has simply changed; that is all.

Now, you have `bundleconfig.json`, instead of `BundleConfig.cs`. Instead of calling `Scripts.Render` to include the bundle, you simply reference the bundled script directly. Likewise with your style.

By default, there is a single bundle for each `site.js` and `site.css` that are "bundled" (and minified) into `site.min.js` and `site.min.css`, respectively. So, you'd just do:

```
<environment names="Staging,Production">
    <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</environment>
```

The `environment` tags simply determine when this HTML will be included in the output. Here, that's only when the enviroment is Staging or Production. The script tag is a hard-reference to the "bundle". This is functionality equivalent to what you would have achieved with something like:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/site")
```

Which, itself, would only have rendered the following script tag:

```
<script src="~/bundles/site?v=abc123"></script>
```

In other words, you don't need the `Scripts.Render` and `Styles.Render` methods, since they're pretty useless actually. Even in previous versions of MVC, you could have avoided them and just created tags directly pointing to your bundles.

For more information on how bundling and minification works in ASP.NET Core, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: I appreciate your detailed answer. I sure wish i'd seen at least any of this info covered in one of the otherwise excellent migration docs.